# How do i check if a cursor is inside a circle on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, logic

i am very unsure on how to do this idea. i have tried researching myself but the solutions provided do not work with my code nor do i want to implement those solutions. i would like it to detect if the person clicked the circle, thats it. here is my code so far, please let me know if any further details are required, thanks.

```
//variable declarations
const cavna = document.getElementById("gameC");
const mainContext = cavna.getContext("2d");
var counter = 0;
var maxCanvas = {
  height: cavna.height,
  width: cavna.width,
}
//TODO:
let amountOfCirclesOnScreen = 0;
//generate a random number between the specified values
function ran(min, max) {
  return (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
//generates a random color hex code
function GenerateRandomColor() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}
//makes a new circle
function GenerateNewCircle() {
  if (amountOfCirclesOnScreen < 1) {
    amountOfCirclesOnScreen++;
    //maybe figure out how to draw a circle (completed)
    mainContext.beginPath();
    //mainContext.moveTo(ran(0, maxCanvas.width), ran(0, maxCanvas.height));
    mainContext.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + 360 * Math.random() + ', 100%, 50%)';
    mainContext.arc(ran(0, maxCanvas.width), ran(0, maxCanvas.height), 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    mainContext.stroke();
    mainContext.fill();
  }
}
//clears tjhe canvas
function clearCanvas() {
  amountOfCirclesOnScreen = 0;
  mainContext.clearRect(0, 0, maxCanvas.width, maxCanvas.height);
}




//checks where u click 
//TODO: check to see if click is on a circle, if yes, clear the canvas
function getMousePosition(event) {
  let x = maxCanvas.width - event.clientX;
  let y = maxCanvas.height - event.clientY;
  alert("Coordinate x: " + x + 
    " | Coordinate y: " + y);
}
cavna.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  getMousePosition(e);
});





GenerateNewCircle();

setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById("counter").innerText = amountOfCirclesOnScreen;
}, 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is easy:

Find the [distance](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php) from the center of the circle to the `event` location. If the distance is less than the radius, then the point is in the circle. If you only have height and width dimensions, the center of the circle is at `w/2,h/2`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work well, could you maybe redo the answer to help in my specific case?

Comment: @user22616583 If you want me to redo this answer, you need to tell me exactly what exactly "does not work well".

Comment: The mouse position seems to be messed up. I can't really go into more detail as I don't  understand the problem myself.